# Parametrized Test vs. Theory vs. Hard coded in pre defined test

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I want to test the exact same behavior on n different instances of class X (x1, x2, ... xn) with two different instances of class Y (y1, y2, .. , yn), but I want to test with the same index.

I mean test x1 with y1, x2 with y2 and so on in the test:
@Test
TestXandY(X x, Y y)

I couldn't think of an easy way to do it with JUnit parameterized tests or Theories, but maybe i am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with JUnit's `Parameterized` runner.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class YourTest {
  @Parameters
  public static Object[][] dataSets() {
    return new Object[][] {
      { new X("x1"), new Y("y1") },
      { new X("x2"), new Y("y2") },
      ...
    }
  }

  @Parameter(0)
  public X x;

  @Parameter(1)
  public Y y;

  @Test
  public void checkSomething() {
    //do something with x and y.
  } 
}
```